# React Native Packager with Resolve Fallback

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, webpack

I am trying to include [this library](https://github.com/dashevo/platform/tree/master/packages/wallet-lib) in React Native. I get errors because it's building it assuming its for NodeJS where it uses some core modules that are not present in React Native. I know it can be build for web, and I see the webpack file [including all the libraries that need to be mocked](https://github.com/dashevo/platform/blob/a62963a7538600439cde889c9efa61d8d8e14ed7/packages/wallet-lib/webpack.config.js#L15) for this task to succeed. React native however does not use webpack. What is the equivalent configuration in the React Native Packager?

```
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      fs: false,
      crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
      buffer: require.resolve('buffer/'),
      assert: require.resolve('assert/'),
      url: require.resolve('url/'),
      path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
      http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
      https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
      stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
      util: require.resolve('util/'),
      os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
      zlib: require.resolve('browserify-zlib'),
      events: require.resolve('events/'),
      string_decoder: require.resolve('string_decoder/'),
    },
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
  },
```

Comment: Can you replace Metro bundler with   this package manager - https://github.com/callstack/repack. It's built on top of  Webpack